# Intuition for why finite integral domain is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

So I am not getting the intuition for why every finite integral domain is a field. I mean I saw the proof but still I feel like its somehow not intuitive to me of why finiteness of integral domain implies that it must be a field. For example if we take $\mathbb{Z}$ it is indeed integral domain but not a field since its inverse doesn't exist in $\mathbb{Z}$. If someone could maybe clarify me for a better picture for the intuition that would be great.

Comment: What proof(s) have you seen for this fact?

Comment: What proof did you see? In an integral domain, multiplication (by a fixed element) is injective. If the integral domain is finite, injectivity of multiplication (by a fixed element) entails surjectivity, and thus bijectivity. That's a fundamental, well known, and often used fact about maps on finite sets from combinatorics. Isn't this nice and intuitive enough?

Comment: That we can just multiply the elements in this integral domain by some arbitrarily fixed number in our set then we can for that element we can see that we can get its inverse and then we can do it for other elements. I mean yes, sure I understand the proof but somehow I feel I am not getting the intuition 100 %.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between a finite and infinite integral domain (like $\Bbb Z$) is very clear here: multiplication by a fixed element does *not* make a surjective function of $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$ unless the element you picked is $1$ or $-1$. Just consider the map $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ given by $x\mapsto 2x$.

However, multiplication by a nonzero element is always *injective* in a domain. Since injectivity and surjectivity are equivalent on finite sets, multiplication by a nonzero element in a finite domain make a surjective map.

So then, for a given nonzero $x$, there always exists a $y$ such that $xy=1$.

Comment: I see that makes sense to me ye now ! thank you rschwieb.

Answer (score 6):

Rschwieb's answer is likely the best way to think about things here. However, I personally like this approach, which I find very intuitive. Maybe you will find it helpful as well.

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $x$ be a nonzero element of $R$. Then consider the set

$$S = \{x, x^{2}, x^{3}, \ldots\}$$

It follows that $S$ must be finite, since $R$ is finite. Hence, it follows that $x^{i} = x^{j}$ for some $i > j$ (without loss of generality). But this means that $x^{j}(x^{i-j}-1) = 0$, and since $R$ is an integral domain, this means that $x^{j} = 0$ or $x^{i-j}-1=0$. But $x^{j}\neq 0$ since $x \neq 0$, so we must have $x^{i-j}=1$. Since $i > j, i-j \geq 1$, so $x(x^{i-j-1})=1$, i.e. $x^{-1} = x^{k}$ for some $k \geq 0$.

Note that this breaks down right at the start for an infinite integral domain - there's no way we can conclude $S$ is finite! You can see this easily with $\mathbb{Z}$.